# UTF-8 error with the python open() function

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8

I wrote a simple code in python the only opens and read a file

```
def read_text():
    quotes = open("‪C:/Users/Matteo/Desktop/quotes.txt")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read()
    print(contents_of_file)
    quotes.close()
read_text()
```

When i try to execute it this is what appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\read.py", line 6, in <module>
read_text()
File "C:\Python27\read.py", line 2, in read_text
quotes = open("â€ªC:/Users/Matteo/Desktop/quotes.txt")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '\xe2\x80\xaaC:/Users  /Matteo/Desktop/quotes.txt'
```

Searching on the internet i understood that the problem is that IDLE recognizes an Unicode character before C, \xe2\x80\xaa, that is a "LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING". I have no idea of what is this and how to remove from my code.

Comment: Do you have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (or some other encoding) line in the beginning of your source code file? I think it should be `utf-8`

Comment: @AndrewCherevatkin IDLE asked me to add that string and i did it but nothing changed

Comment: @melpomene Oh i did it and now it works, thank you, how can i mark your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains an invisible character (probably because you copy/pasted the filename from somewhere). Try deleting the `"C:` part and retyping it.